# How can I use the Permissionsdispatcher library for the new Android M runtime permissions?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, android-6.0-marshmallow

I came across a Cheese Factory article (google it because I cannot post more than 2 links with my reputation) which explains how to handle the new permissions system for Android Marshmallow. In the article, he references the [Permissionsdispatcher library](http://hotchemi.github.io/PermissionsDispatcher/)
which aims to reduce boilerplate code. So I downloaded the library demo from GitHub but I get an error which says MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher cannot be resolved. From what I can understand, [this class](https://gist.github.com/hotchemi/5dc89c02399c2419fab7) should be generated. How can I generate it to remove the error ?

`MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    // delegate the permission handling to generated method
    // MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher cannot be resolved
    MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults);
}
```

Comment: let's improve your reputation, this is a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a developer. Thanks for your using.

1. Check your IDE's setting whether annotation processing is allowed or not.
2. You said, "which is a fork of the PermissionsDispatcher repo" but what you mean? Forked the repo and run the sample module?

Comment: 1. Where is this located in the IDE Settings menu ? 
2. yes

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem. The sample can now run in a virtual device.

Comment: @charlesfranciscodev i m facing same problem in studio version 1.5 how can i genrate this helper class please help me

Answer (score 1):

Like described here https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher#must

You will have to add the `@RuntimePermissions` Annotation to your activity and a `@NeedsPermission` Annotation to a method at least.

In your **build.gradle** add the following:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:1.2.1@aar'
  apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:1.2.1'
}
```

The android-apt plugin will take care of the annotation processing.
After building the project you should be able to use the generated class.

Comment: These annotations are already in the code which is a fork of the [PermissionsDispatcher repo](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher). Also when I run the app I get the following error: 

`Error:Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'mavenAndroidJavadocs' during up-to-date check.  See stacktrace for details.
> Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\dev1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-4\android.jar;C:\Users\dev1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'.`

Comment: Looks like you are using maven? The PremissionDispatcher Library is based on gradle and uses android-apt to process the annotation (see the edit of my answer)

Comment: I added the lines mentioned in the edit in PermissionsDispatcher\build.gradle but I get this error. `The android or android-library plugin must be applied to the project` It crashes at the  following line : `apply plugin: 'android-apt'`.

Comment: You will have to built your own project (where you want to apply the permission handling) with gradle. This should of course be a project where the gradle 'android' or 'android-library' is included. I do not know if there is something like android-apt for maven, so I would recomend to build your app with gradle.

Comment: which build.gradle should be modified ?
1. PermissionsDispatcher\build.gradle
2. PermissionsDispatcher\permissionsdispatcher\build.gradle
3. PermissionsDispatcher\permissionsdispatcher-processor\build.gradle
4. PermissionsDispatcher\permissionsdispatcher-sample\build.gradle

Comment: There is no need to modify any build.gradle files when using the sample. See the answer above. Thanks for your help anyway.